where have i done a mistake here for finding the best approximation to a function?
I was given the following problem from "Harmonic analysis" course (I don't have solutions)
"given vector space $C\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$ and the following inner product $$\left\langle f,g\right\rangle =\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}}f\left(x\right)\cdot\overline{g\left(x\right)}dx$$
and $W=$ span $\left\{ 1,\sin x,\cos x,x\right\}$ and $f=|x|$, find $g\in W$ such that $g$ is the best approximation of $f$ in $W$"
this means using the Gram-Schmidt procedure so here's what I did:
$$\begin{cases}
u_1 = 1\\
u_2 = \sin(x) - \frac{\left\langle \sin(x),1\right\rangle}{\left\langle 1,1\right\rangle}\cdot1\\
u_3 = \cos(x) - \frac{\left\langle \cos(x),\sin(x)\right\rangle}{\left\langle \sin(x),\sin(x)\right\rangle}\cdot \sin(x) - \frac{\left\langle \cos(x),1\right\rangle}{\left\langle 1,1\right\rangle}\cdot1\\
u_4 = x - \frac{\left\langle x,\cos(x)\right\rangle}{\left\langle \cos(x),\cos(x)\right\rangle}\cdot \cos(x) - \frac{\left\langle x,\sin(x)\right\rangle}{\left\langle \sin(x),\sin(x)\right\rangle}\cdot \sin(x) - \frac{\left\langle x,1\right\rangle}{\left\langle 1,1\right\rangle}\cdot1\\
\end{cases}$$
now all of the inner products cancel out (because the integration of odd function over symmetric domain) except for the sin coefficient in $u_4$ which comes up to 2 so we have the following vectors:
$$\begin{cases}
u_1 = 1\\
u_2 = \sin(x)\\
u_3 = \cos(x)\\
u_4 = x - 2\sin(x)
\end{cases}$$
now to find $g$ we need the following sum $ \sum_{i=1}^{4}\left\langle f,e_{i}\right\rangle \cdot e_{i} $ so I need to normalize the vectors I found by each norm, you can quickly get that:
$$\begin{cases}
\left\Vert u_1 \right\Vert = \sqrt2\\
\left\Vert u_2 \right\Vert = 1\\
\left\Vert u_3 \right\Vert = 1\\
\left\Vert u_4 \right\Vert = \sqrt{\dfrac{2\cdot {\pi}^{2}-12}{3}}\\
\end{cases}$$
then calculating the Fourier coefficients:
$$\begin{cases}
\left\langle |x|,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\rangle = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\left\langle |x|,\sin(x)\right\rangle = 0\\
\left\langle |x|,\cos(x)\right\rangle = -\frac{2}{\pi}\\
\left\langle |x|,e_4\right\rangle = 0\\
\end{cases}$$
so we end up with $$g=\sum_{i=1}^{4}\left\langle f,e_{i}\right\rangle \cdot e_{i}= \frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{2\cos(x)}{\pi}$$
and when I plot this at Desmos it doesn't look close enough, when I solved other similar problems the difference between the functions was barely noticeable here it's apparent that something has gone wrong.


You should have $\left\langle |x|,\cos(x)\right\rangle = -\frac{4}{\pi}$.

@J.G. you're correct! i cant belive it all comes down to a single factor of 2 at the end
thanks!

You do not need to use Gram-Schmidt procedure. The function $|x|$ is orthogonal to $\sin x$ and $x.$ The functions $2^{-1/2}$ and $\cos x$ form an orthonormal system. So you need to calculate $\langle |x|,2^{-1/2}\rangle $ and $\langle |x|,\cos x\rangle .$
